# In lisp, do parens sometimes mean a list constructor and sometimes evaluation?

Tags: lisp

I'm a total beginner in lisp. Consider the following two examples:

```
guile -c "(display 2)" # prints 2
guile -c "display 2" # doesn't print 2
```

I've been thinking of parens as list constructors, with the idea that they aren't needed for grouping in this language, because there is no operator precedence. But it seems in this case that the parens have the effect of causing the expression to be evaluated, which I guess acts like a kind of pattern-matching: if the interpreter sees something that looks like `display X`, the definition of `display` causes it to transform it into something else.

Am I interpreting this behavior correctly? If so, then how would I generate a list whose first element was the function `display`?

If parens have the effect of triggering evaluation, then is this a special-case behavior that only occurs when the first element of the list is a function? E.g., I can do this

```
guile -c "(display display)"
```

which outputs a description of the `display` function's type and name.

Comment: `display 2` this is two separate expressions, but not one. *how would I generate a list whose first element was the function `display`?* `(list display)` *they aren't needed for grouping in this language, because there is no operator precedence* `(+ 1 2 * 3 4 5 6)` is this `(+ 1 2 (* 3 4) 5 6)` or `(+ 1 2 (* 3 4 5) 6)` or `(+ 1 2 (* 3 4 5 6))` or something else?

Comment: @PetSerAl: Thanks. I think that should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a clear distinction between reading and evaluating forms:

- First of all, the code is read, transforming a string to a tree of expressions. In the case of Lisp, the AST is also a Lisp value. If your input is the string `"(display 1)"`, you are reading a literal list which first value is the `display` symbol, and the second element is 1.
- When you take this expression and evaluate it, either automatically from the REPL or by a call to `eval`, you are asking the language to interpret Lisp data as code. When this value is a list, under normal evaluation rules, this is a function call. If your form is quoted, like `(quote (display 1))`, which can be written `'(display 1)`, then the result of the evaluation is simply the data being quoted, here the list.

What you want is for the code to produce, at execution time, a list whose first element is `display`. As seen above, you could easily quote a read-time list, if the data you return is constant, for example `'(display)`. But most of the time, the data you generate at runtime is composed of other evaluated data, and the way you build a list is by calling the `list` function:

```
(list 'display 1)
```

The above reads as a list of three elements, namely the symbol `list`, the list `(quote display)` and the number 1. When evaluated, this list is a function call, so all arguments are evaluted: `(quote display)` evaluates as the symbol `display`, and 1 evaluates as itself. Finally, the function associated with `list` is called on those values.

Note that the reader in Lisp also probably calls `list` under the hood, which is one of the fun meta-circular aspect of Lisp.